# Building a website - best practice and architecture with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Any pointers on best practice when it comes to architecure on the web. I've just learnt a bit of Ruby and wish to use it to build websites. I'm in no hurry, I want to learn the best way not a quick'n'dirty way as this is a hobby.

How do i get data from my mySql db to my front end? I know a bit of xhtml / css but how do I now join it all together?

Many thanks for any help...

skipz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at the [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) framework, for several reasons:

- Rails is pretty easy to get up and running with
- Rails incorporates many best practices and established patterns e.g. [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) and [ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)
- It didn't used to be the case, but Rails now has lots of [high quality](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and free [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and supporting resources to help you learn
- Lots of [websites and applications](http://rubyonrails.org/applications) have already been built using Rails
- Rails is under active development and the future of the framework looks [pretty bright](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2008/12/23/merb-gets-merged-into-rails-3)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest method is to use an existing framework, with [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) being the big dog in town.

Answer (score 4):

[Getting Started with Ruby on Rails](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/gettingstartedwithrubyonrails)